# Co-ordinates of the 3rd point in a triangle

Tags: php, geometry, cartesian-coordinates

Given :

```
Point A (a1,b1)
Point B (a2,b2)
Distance between A and B
Distance between A and C
Angle between AB and AC = 90deg
```

Have to find :
`C(a3,b3)`

I have the co-ordinates of 2 points A(x,y) and B(p,q) but want to find the co-ordinates of a third point C(m,n).

 I know the distance between A and B, A and C, and the angle between A and C which is 90deg. 
I know this is simple Pythagoras theorem. But how do I implement it in php and what would be the formula?

Comment: There are two possibilities for the point C, which one do you want to get?

Comment: I have to find both the possibilities.

Comment: OK, I've posted both possibilites in my answer.

Comment: thanks a lot. But can you tell me which formula did you use. Which equation or theorem. Would be helpful for the future.

Comment: I didn't use the Pythagoras theorem or any other equation. Instead, I simply rotated the vector AB by 90deg (clockwise for the first and counter-clockwise for the second possibility) and then scaled it by `$d / $d0` to give it the correct length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `$x,$y` and `$p,$q` be the given coordinates of A and B, furthermore call `$d` the known distance between A and C and `$d0` the known distance between A and B. By doing a little math you get the following formulae (here I'm directly implementing it in PHP):

```
$m = $x + ($q - $y) * $d / $d0;
$n = $y - ($p - $x) * $d / $d0;
```

There is also a second solution:

```
$m = $x - ($q - $y) * $d / $d0;
$n = $y + ($p - $x) * $d / $d0;
```

**EDIT:** Here is how I got the equations: I rotated the vector AB, which has the coordinates `($p - $x, $q - $y)`, by 90 degrees to obtain `($q - $y, -($p - $x))` and `(-($q - $y), $p - $x)` (depending whether clockwise or counter-clockwise) and then got the vector AC by scaling it with `$d / $d0` (the ratio of their lengths). Now I just translated the vector by `($x, $y)` to get `($m, $n)`.

Maybe this can be implemented more elegantly by using a vector class in PHP or even a whole library, but I think for this simple calculation it is much easier to implement it "by hand".